# jQuery.validate.js and asp.net master pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I have jQuery in various files, and recently I have needed to change items in the master page. This has caused various jaavscript includes to stop working. Stackoverflow are [suggesting great ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232465/) to solve the issue regarding the get by ID selector.

```
$("#ctl00_ContentMainPane_eliteUser").html
```

However I have a problem where we have used jquery.validate.js to validate form controls, so there is code like this in *external* JS files

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#aspnetForm").validate({
        rules: 
    {
        ctl00$ContentMainPane$txtFirstName:
        {
            required:true,
            CheckAlfaNumeric:true
        },
        ctl00$ContentMainPane$ctl00$ucRFI$txtComments:
        {
            required:true
        }                       

    },
    messages:
    {
        ctl00$ContentMainPane$txtFirstName: 
        {
            required:" Please enter first name"
        },
        ctl00$ContentMainPane$ctl00$ucRFI$txtComments:
        {
            required:"&nbsp;Please enter comments."
        }
    }
    });
    $("#" + GetPlaceholder() + "txtFirstName").blur(function(){
            $("#" + GetPlaceholder() + "txtFirstName").valid();
    });
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("CheckAlfaNumeric", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z\ ]+$/i.test(value);
    }, " Please enter alphabet.");
});
```

Any idea how to prevent the nameing issue of attributes  if the name happens to change due to the master page being amended?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232465/how-to-use-jquery-select-element-by-id-and-asp-net-without-putting-ctl00-everyw)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wait for .NET 4.0, which allows you to specify exactly how the ID's should be constructed ;)

Seriously: you can AFAIK create your rules manually, doing something like (a JS object is nothing but an "array" of properties):

```
var myRules = new Object();
myRules[GetPlaceholder() + "txtFirstName"] = { required:true, CheckAlfaNumeric:true };

var myMessages = new Object();
myMessages[GetPlaceholder() + "txtFirstName"] = { required:"Please enter first name" };

$("#aspnetForm").validate({ rules: myRules, messages: myMessages });
```

Comment: It may just be the .Net o phile in me, but can you make "new Object()" a strongly typed class here?

Comment: no, there is no such concept of a class or a strong type for that matter in JavaScript...

Comment: Dude.  Your "myRules" and "myMessages" saved the day.  Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at 
http://weblogs.asp.net/psperanza/archive/2009/05/07/jquery-selectors-selecting-elements-by-a-partial-id.aspx for partial matches in jQuery.
The only other option I can see is to add the js file contents to the page and use something <%=txtFirstName.ClientID%>

Answer (score 0):

My answer is my modification of veggerby.  Please upvote his response, not mine.  He saved the day.

I'm putting my response here to add a slight caveat.  (I'm doing the Using 'attr("name")).
And to show how to do it with a drop down list.

Not seen is that my content page has a asp.net dropdownlist called "ddlState" and "ddlFavoriteColor".  I put a dummy "--Select--" value in the top of the drop down list items, so I want something where the selectedIndex is greater than zero.

Note, this project is "stuck" with 3.5.  :<  I would have rather done something with the cool 4.0 features.

Yes, my "check" code could be smaller, but for web samples, I like to be a tad verbose over concise to show what is going on.

```
function GetStateDropDownName() {
    var cntlName = $("[id$=_ddlState]").attr("name");
    return cntlName;
}

function GetFavoriteColorDropDownName() {
    var cntlName = $("[id$=_ddlFavoriteColor]").attr("name");
    return cntlName;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("dropdownBoxHasItemSelected", function (value, select, arg) {
        var returnValue = false;
        var selectedIndex = $(select).prop("selectedIndex");
        if (selectedIndex != 0) {
            returnValue = true;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }, "Please select a item.");


    var myRules = new Object();
    myRules[GetStateDropDownName()] = { dropdownBoxHasItemSelected: true };
    myRules[GetFavoriteColorDropDownName()] = { dropdownBoxHasItemSelected: true };

    var myMessages = new Object();
    myMessages[GetStateDropDownName()] = { dropdownBoxHasItemSelected: "Please select a State." };
    myMessages[GetFavoriteColorDropDownName()] = { dropdownBoxHasItemSelected: "Please select a Favorite Color." };


    // Initialize validation on the entire ASP.NET form.
    $("#aspnetForm").validate({
        rules: myRules, messages: myMessages
    });
```