# How can I use jquery to set the selected value of aspnet drop down list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dropdown

I have a c# web user control with an asp drop down list. I want to use jquery or similar to set the selected value based on the url of the website.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="LangSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LangSelect_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="English" Value="English"> English</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Français" Value="Français"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Español" Value="Español"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Deutsch" Value="Deutsch"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I have tried this:

```
<script>
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('de') > 0) {
        $("#LangSelect").val('Deutsch');
    }
</script>
```

However, its giving an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null

Comment: You're missing the `#` at the start of your selector to signify that it is an id lookup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JQuery, select element by ID and ASP.NET without putting ctl00\_ everywhere in the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232465/how-to-use-jquery-select-element-by-id-and-asp-net-without-putting-ctl00-every)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use document ready to make sure your DOM is loaded, and use `LangSelect.ClientID` to get the `LangSelect` ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('de') > 0) {
        $('#<%= LangSelect.ClientID %>').val('Deutsch');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your selector, first, you're missing the `#` at the start to indicate it's an ID, but even then, your element is set `runat="server"` which will change the actual ID of the html element when the page is rendered.

For this you can either add `ClientIDMode="Static"` the the element which will lock the ID, or change your selector to `$([id$=LangSelect])`, I prefer using `ClientIDMode`.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('de') > 0) {
      $('<%=LangSelect.ClientID%>').find('option[value='Deutsch']').prop('selected', true);

```
}
```

});